# How to tell if Safari is using HTTP2?

Tags: safari, http2

I tried all tabs in Web Inspector and didn't find anything useful. Google does not turn up any way either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you switch to the Network tab in the inspector and then open the right details sidebar, you can see the Header information of request and response:

[image: Network tab with details sidebar]

Comment: Ah! How could I miss it… Thanks a lot, Harald!

Comment: It looks like as of macOS Monterey 12.2 Beta (21D5039d) & Safari Version 15.3 (17612.4.8.1.1), this is now in the `Sources` tab not the `Network` tab. I **think** this was likely changed in a previous version, but this is the version I'm running. So if it's not in the `Network` tab, check in the `Sources` tab.